# Prototype mismatch error (perl)

Tags: perl, module

I am getting this strange error when importing a module I wrote into my Dancer app.

```
Prototype mismatch: sub main::from_json: none vs ($@) at mymodule.pm line 6.
Prototype mismatch: sub main::to_json: none vs ($@) at mymodule.pm line 6.
```

I guess this is because in my module I'm importing the perl JSON module.

Everything seems to perform fine, but I'm wondering what this error/warning is all about? I can't seem to find anything about it online.

Comment: Do you by "importing the JSON module" mean "pre-declaring the subroutines from_json and to_json"? With something like `sub from_json;`?

Comment: no I mean I use the header 

"use JSON;"

in my module, which is a file named mymodule.pm (containing a package of the same name). Then from my application file I import that module file with "use mymodule;".

Comment: Don't really understand why this question has been downvoted. Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: did you use from_json and to_json passing 1 or 2 scalar arguments?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable guess, but I answered my own question below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another situation where this arises is when *some other module you have loaded* defines a from_json/to_json.  An example I've hit a couple times recently is with Dancer.  If you have a package with

```
package Foo;

use Dancer qw/:syntax/;
use JSON;

1;
```

You will get that warning because (apparently) Dancer with the :syntax import puts a from_json and to_json into your namespace.

A quick solution in this situation is to just explicitly import nothing from JSON:

```
package Foo;

use Dancer qw/:syntax/;
use JSON qw//;

1;
```

Then in your code you will need to use the full package name to get JSON's subs, like this:

```
my $hash = JSON::from_json('{"bob":"sally"}');
```

In a situation like this, though, *you want to use the full package names* so it's clear which function you're getting--there are multiple declarations of to_json/from_json, so let's be very clear which one we mean.

If you put the following in Foo.pm and run with "perl Foo.pm", with and without the `qw//` after the `use JSON`, you can see how it works:

```
package Foo;

use Dancer qw/:syntax/;
use JSON qw//;

print Dumper( JSON::from_json('{"bob":"sally"}') ); use Data::Dumper;

1;
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe Dancer/2 provides `to_json` and `from_json` to you, so you don't have to use JSON.

This will work:

```
use Dancer2 ':syntax';
get '/cheeseburgers' => {
    return to_json($restaurant->make_cheeseburgers);
}
```

Comment: very true. it's included into the package, not only dancer2 but dancer (the original version) as well. Still, I was using perl packages incorrectly, and this error was more of a general one, pertaining to the order in which "use" and "require" should appear on a script.

Answer (score 3):

The reason I was getting this error was because in my own module, I was using the use directive and importing JSON and other modules BEFORE I declared my own package namespace, with

```
package mymodule
```

instead of AFTER. The package declaration has to come first.

Answer (score 1):

See Prototypes in [perlsub](http://p3rl.org/perlsub). The functions `from_json` and `to_json` were defined with different prototypes than used in the code.