# Scrambled umlauts since upgrade from JSON1 to JSON2 in Perl

Tags: json, perl

I wondered why some german umlauts were scrambled on our page.
Then i found out that the recent version of JSON (i use 2.07) does convert strings in an other manner than JSON 1.5.

Problem here is that i have a hash with strings like

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $test = {
  'fields' => 'überrascht'
};
```

`print Dumper(to_json($test));` gives me

```
$VAR1 = "{ \"fields\" : \"\x{fc}berrascht\" } ";
```

Using the old module using

```
$json = JSON->new();
print Dumper ($json->to_json($test));
```

gives me (the correct result)

```
$VAR1 = '{"fields":[{"title":"überrascht"}]}';
```

So umlauts are scrammbled using the new JSON 2 module.

**What do i need to get them correct?**

**Update:** It might be bad to use Data::Dumper to show output, because Dumper uses its own encoding. Well, a difference in the result from Dumper shows that anything is treated differently here. It might be better to describe the backend as Brad mentioned:
The json string gets printed using Template-Toolkit and then gets assigned to a javascript variable for further use. The correct javascript shows something like this

```
{
    "title" : "Geändert",
},
```

using the new module i get

```
{
    "title" : "GeÃ¤ndert",
},
```

The target page is in 8859-1 (latin1).
Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the encoding of the file and what encoding does your terminal expect? It's hard to tell what used to get produced.

Comment: If you can still run using the old version of the module, what do you get if you add `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;`?

Comment: Which backend are your examples using? `print $_,"\n" for grep { m(JSON/) } keys %INC`

Comment: @ikegami: i get \374 istead of the correct "ü" i got before when i use the old version of the module (in an identical second system)

Comment: @BradGilbert: the json string gets printed using Template-Toolkit and then gets assigned to a javascript variable for further use

Comment: @ikegami: i get \377 instead of the correct 'ü' using the old version of the module

Comment: Are you saying that DD with `Useeqq=1` gives `"...\374..."`? That means the string contains `ü` encoded using iso-8859-1, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encode_json` instead. According to the manual it converts the given Perl data structure to a UTF-8 encoded, binary string.

**Regarding your update:** If you actually want to produce JSON in Latin1 (ISO-8859-1), you can try:

```
to_json($test, { latin1 => 1 })
```

Or

```
JSON->new->latin1->encode($test)
```

Note that if you dump the result, getting `\x{fc}` for `ü` is correct in this case. I guess that the root of your problem is that you receive text in Perl's UTF-8 format from somewhere. In this case, the `latin1` option of the JSON module is needed.

You can also try to use `ascii` instead of `latin1` as the safest option.

Another solution might be to specify an output encoding for Template-Toolkit. I don't know if that's possible. Or, you could encode your result as Latin1 in the final step before sending it to the client.

Comment: Works for me. Make sure that your source file is either encoded in Latin1, or add `use utf8` if it's encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: i tried to encode the string in latin1, but the result did not change (JSON->new->latin1->encode($str)

Comment: +1 there was another json_encoding of the data that i missed - works like a charm now - thx

Comment: concerning json: can you tell me why i still get the warning in the log file: Prototype mismatch: sub ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::PerlRun::mypath_myfile_2epl::from_json: none vs ($@) at mypath_myfile.pl line 6.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770114/prototype-mismatch-error-perl).

Comment: i do not have any package declaration at all in that script

Answer (score 5):

`\x{fc}` is `ü`, at least in Latin-1, Latin-9 etc. Also, `ü` is codepoint `U+00FC` in Unicode. However, we want UTF-8 (I suppose). The easiest solution to get UTF-8 string literals is to save your Perl source code with this encoding, and put a `use utf8;` at the top of your script.

Then, encoding the string as JSON yields correct output:

```
use strict; use warnings; use utf8;
use Data::Dumper; use JSON;
print Dumper encode_json {fields => "nicht überrascht"};
```

The `encode_json` assumes UTF-8. Read the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.57/lib/JSON.pm) for more info.

Output:

```
$VAR1 = '{"fields":"nicht überrascht"}';
```

(JSON module version: 2.53)

Comment: @ikegami I realized that, thus the “save your Perl source code with this encoding [UTF-8]”. Using UTF8 source code is just one easy way to solve the issue, there are also your ways to do it.

Comment: ack, overlooked that part of the sentence.

Comment: wow, just read the rest of your post, and it's very misleading. `use utf8;` doesn't produce UTF-8-encoded strings (and it definitely doesn't produce string literals of any kind). It actually does the opposite (decode from UTF-8). "UTF-8 string literals" should be "upgraded strings".

Comment: Secondly, `encode_json` doesn't "assume UTF-8", whatever that means. Maybe you meant it expects strings to contain text (Unicode code points), but it doesn't care whether they're upgraded or not. Maybe you meant it "produces UTF-8"?

Comment: the source code is in cp1252, but this has not been a problem before, the data is coming from the database

Answer (score 5):

```
my $json_text = to_json($data);
```

is short for

```
my $json_text = JSON->new->encode($data);
```

This returns a string of Unicode Code Points. U+00FC is indeed the correct Unicode code point for "ü", so the output is correct. (As proof, the HTML source for that is actually `"&#xFC;"`.)

It's hard to tell what your original output actually contained (since you showed non-ASCII characters), so it's hard to determine what your problem is actually.

But one thing you must do before outputing the string is to convert it from a string of code points into bytes, say, by using [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode)'s `encode` or `encode_utf8`.

```
my $json_cp1252 = encode('cp1252', to_json($data));

my $json_utf8 = encode_utf8(to_json($data));
```

If the appropriate encoding is UTF-8, you can also use any of the following:

```
my $json_utf8 = to_json($data, { utf8 => 1 });

my $json_utf8 = encode_json($data);

my $json_utf8 = JSON->new->utf8->encode($data);
```

Comment: actually i use JSON->new->utf8->encode($string) already to give this string to Template engine

Answer (score 2):

Strictly-speaking, Latin-1-encoded JSON is not valid JSON.  The [JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) allows UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 encodings.

If you want to be standards-compliant or you want to ensure your JSON will be compatible with both your current pages and future UTF-8-based pages, you need to use `JSON->new->utf8->encode($str)`.  Being strict about generated valid JSON could save you lots of headaches in the future.

You can translate UTF-8 JSON to Latin-1 using client-side Javascript if you need to, using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396742/2323695).

The `ascii` option also produces valid JSON, by escaping any non-ASCII characters using valid JSON unicode escapes.  But the `latin1` option does not, and therefore should be avoided IMHO.   The `utf8(0)` option should be avoided too unless you specify an encoding when writing the data out to clients: `utf8(0)` is subtly different from the `utf8` option in that it generates Perl character strings instead of byte strings.  If you do any I/O using character strings without specifying an encoding, Perl will translate it on-the-fly back to Latin-1.  The `utf8` option generates raw UTF-8 bytes, which are perfect for doing raw I/O.